# Intel i7 2600 or i5 2500 for development machines?

Tags: computer-building

I'm pricing machines that will be primarily used for C# development using Visual Studio, and can't see a reason to pay $200 more for an Intel 2600 vs. a 2500. You gain 100MHz, 2MB of cache, and HT (this last one seems to be the selling point).

Is there something I'm missing that makes these worth the $200 extra? I'd much rather drop a portion of that into getting another hard drive and slapping the two of them in RAID 0. Seems like a better investment, and a quarter of the price.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). This question is more or less a shopping recommendation and therefore considered off-topic here, as it's much too localized.

Comment: this might be much better off re-phrased and over on Programmers.SE e.g. Ask "does the Hyperthreading (as opposed to real core count) on i7's contribute significantly to C# build times?"